# python os.env cannot find JAVA_HOME variable

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04. In python 2.7.3 when I run

```
import os

print os.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
```

it returns

`None`

When I run `echo $JAVA_HOME` it returns `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/`.

Why can't python read my environment variables?

I encountered this problem in Jpype and narrowed it down to that fundamental issue.

Comment: Where was the environment variable obtained or defined?

Comment: it is defined in `/etc/environment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha silly me! All I needed was a good old reboot!

Answer (score 0):

Try [exporting](http://ss64.com/bash/export.html) JAVA_HOME.  In the shell do this:

```
export JAVA_HOME
```

Then try your script.

Another example:

```
$ foo=bar 
$ echo $foo 
bar 
$ python 
>>> import os
>>> os.getenv("foo")
>>> quit() 
$ export foo
$ python 
>>> import os
>>> os.getenv("foo") 
'bar'
>>> quit()
```